# php regex and chinese characters

Tags: php, regex, parsing, extract, cjk

I'm trying to extract the date "25/01/2005", the company name "A One Investment Company Limited 大一投資有限公司", the Chinese name "大一投資有限公司" and the licence number "ABG896" from this string:

Name: A One Investment Company Limited 大一投資有限公司(ABG896) Date of Licence: 25/01/2005 Remarks

---

However I have no idea how to extract all the data INCLUDING the chinese signs into an array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your string is encoded as utf-8, set `/u` mode and use `\p{L}` to match unicode letters or use `\X` as a replacement for `.`. Note that `\X` matches newlines, whereas `.` does not.

See [this page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) for further details.

Comment: The `u` flag stands for "UTF-8" so the source string must also be encoded as such.